# Using same Context Everywhere?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I am dynamically creating a lot of views within my application. Each requires context.

Should I just use one instance of the context and then pass them to everyone or should I use different instances.

In other words, which is better, this -

```
Context context = this;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    SomeView view = new SomeView(context);
}
```

or this -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
    SomeView view = new SomeView(this);
}
```

**Note:** Views will stay on the screen for a long time.

Comment: Dear viewer, I'm sorry if I posted a noobish question. Please explain the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in the same class, you can use directly "`this`", 
In case you need the context of other class in current class use `Context c = X.class;`
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please be advised that there is no real difference between your two variants.

In the second example you do not create another instance of `this`! All that Java does in the background is to pass a pointer as a reference to `this` to your constructor. Whereas, in the first example, you pass a reference to `this` to `context` passing the same reference to your constructor.

This implies that, if you change something in your context inside a view, the context changes in every other view as well. Remember that thread-safety is not given out-of-the-box, be careful.

You might do a read-up on the inner workings of Java: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29#Automatic_memory_management) is a great start.